# Is there a citation available for 'a growing rebellion' against strict typing systems?

Tags: static-typing, dynamic-typing

The [FAQ](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html) for the new [Go language](http://golang.org/) explicitly makes this claim:

> There is a growing rebellion against cumbersome type systems like those of Java and C++, pushing people towards dynamically typed languages such as Python and JavaScript.

Is there (non-anecdotal) data to actually support such a claim?  I've always found dynamic typing sloppy and tiresome, but if I'm losing touch I at least want some warning.

Comment: The question itself doesn't actually relate specifically to Go.  I'm curious about an assertion made in a FAQ and whether it has any actual basis in reality.

Comment: Yeah, but it's so argumentative it hurts.  This is a discussion, not a question.

Comment: I've switched it to a community wiki.  And accusing people of rep whoring is kind of weak since there's *naturally* going to be a flood of discussion when a new language is announced by a company like Google.

Comment: I'd say that the statement itself is argumentative, but this question is asking for what amounts to a citation.  As such, I'd say this is a pretty objective question.

Comment: Good edit, Jed. I think the question is quite legitimate now, but it already has 4 close votes, so it's likely to be closed.

Comment: Thanks Jed / Kaizer, much better question format than I originally came up with and still gets the same point across

Comment: This is frustrating: we need the ability to vote against closing *before* a question is actually closed. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close

Comment: I think 'sloppy' is a better description than 'dynamic'.  People seem to love it but I think Python is like a cancer that is overstepping its intended use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd call it a trend, not a rebellion, but I see the same in our company moving from C (25 years ago) over C++(20 years) and java (12 years) to javascript and python (2 years).

One of the reasons could be, that scripting seems to be more agile and better for rapid development (which I actually doubt). That impression came along when some developers started nice applications in impressive development speed, while the 'old OO-family' often came up with (over-)complicated application architectures which showed a depressing progress.

I think it doesn't has to be scripted if time to market is a criterion (but sometimes it helps to get rid of old habits)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with kai1968, it is more of a trend. Here is a good paper done by IEEE that will give you a better understanding [Developers Shift to Dynamic Programming Languages](http://www.computer.org/portal/web/csdl/abs/html/mags/co/2007/02/r2012.htm)

Comment: Link only answer wit broken link - could be deleted.